# Binding a ComboBoxes itemssource with a Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Why would the first example not update the comboBoxes itemsSource, but the second would? As far as I knew, if I explicitly called OnPropertyChanged() then it would notify the GUI and get the new value from my VM.

example 1 - doesn't update in GUI (no items in cbo)

```
        // this is the property it's bound to
        this.AvailableSleepTimes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // gets a dictionary with values
        Dictionary<string, int> allTimes = ReminderTimesManager.GetReminderTimes();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> pair in allTimes)
        {
            // logic for adding to the dictionary
            this.AvailableSleepTimes.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

        }
        OnPropertyChanged(() => this.AvailableSleepTimes);
```

example 2 - updates in GUI (cbo is filled)

```
        // this is the property it's bound to
        this.AvailableSleepTimes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // gets a dictionary with values
        Dictionary<string, int> allTimes = ReminderTimesManager.GetReminderTimes();

        Dictionary<string, int> newList = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> pair in allTimes)
        {
            // logic for adding to the dictionary
            newList.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

        }
        this.AvailableSleepTimes = newList;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => this.AvailableSleepTimes);
```

Answer (score 1):

No property changed notifications are created when you add/remove an item to the dictionary.  However, when you reassign, the property, it fires the OnPropertyChanged and updates the GUI.

In order for the GUI to update when the collection is added to, you need to use the ObservableCollection class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/

Comment: Note that OP explicitly fires a PropertyChanged event. The reason why the UI doesn't update is that the actual dictionary instance hasn't changed, hence the change notification is ignored by the Binding target. Besides that, you'll also find ObservableDictionary implementations on the internet.